# Wireshark shows plain number in place of longitude and latitude values

Tags: coordinates, wireshark, latitude-longitude, wireshark-dissector

I am facing issue with coordinate calculation (Longitude and Latitude). I have a pcap file when I open it with Wireshark I am getting the packet as shown below -

```
Latitude: 52.5125915 (52°30'45.33"N) (525125915)
Longitude: 13.3335368 (13°20'00.73"E) (133335368)
```

But when I am copying the value manually or exporting the pcap into a JSON file I am getting the value as (525125915).

So I need to know how to convert the value into "Decimal Degrees" format.

Note:

1. I have searched for conversion options but all the articles I found refer to "DD to DMS" or "DMS to DD" conversion but I could not find any formula / documents to convert a number to coordinate degree.
2. I have also tried converting the number to degree but it will not work for above case!

Thanks in advance.

Shahneel

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for most of the sites they are doing it like following example -

```
int(val)/10000000.0
```

For 525125915/10000000 it is now showing as 52.5125915

Thanks